# iOS: How to save a video in your directory and play it afterwards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, mpmovieplayer

I am working in an `iOS` project. I want may application to download a `video` from the internet `programmatically`. Then I want to play it. I know how can I play a local video from the `Resources`, but my question is how could I download it , and the find it to be played.
I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to run the video.

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I found the answer**

here I saved the video

```
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://videoURL";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString  *documentsDirectory ;
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"videoName.mp4"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

and this code is for playing the video form its directory

```
    NSString  *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"videoName.mp4"];

//video URL
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid url of the video, Apple provides an API to directly buffer videos with `NSURL`.

1. You should hold a reference to the `MPMoviePlayerController` object from the controller so that ARC doesn't release the object.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController* mc;
   ```
2. Make the URL

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/video.mp4"];
   ```
3. Init `MPMoviePlayerController` with that URL

   ```
   MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   ```
4. Resize the controller, add it to your view, play it and enjoy the video.

   ```
   self.mc = controller; // so that ARC doesn't release the controller
   controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
   [controller play]; //Start playing
   ```

For more detail you can visit this [playing video from a url in ios7](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/playing-video-from-a-url-in-ios7/)

Comment: Thanks @Abubakr for your answer , but this is not what I looking for 
I don't want to play it from its URL .

Comment: Can you tell me where you want to play it from?

Comment: I want to run it later with offline mode.
Thanks a lot a found the answer and I have  wrote it below.

Comment: ok ok, so you wanted to save the video and then play it from there. got it.